# PhpSpreadsheet's formating the date importing from XLSX

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Good Day. I use PhpSpreadsheet's library to import xlsx.

In The column I in xlsx I have this value `20/10/1970 00:00:00` displaying like `1970-10-20 00:00:00` but when I import it:

```
$dataArray = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
->rangeToArray(
    'A2:AO3',    // The worksheet range that we want to retrieve
    NULL,        // Value that should be returned for empty cells
    NULL,        // Should formulas be calculated (the equivalent of getCalculatedValue() for each cell)
    TRUE,        // Should values be formatted (the equivalent of getFormattedValue() for each cell)
    TRUE         // Should the array be indexed by cell row and cell column
);
```

I receive strange `["I"] => float(25861)` Please Help me to get Carbon data in this field.

If I try to convert this float like a timestamp I receive `01/01/1970` not `10/20/1970`

Other date I receive like `["J"] => float(43195.4092014)`

Answer (score 10):

In Excel dates are not the same as in other software/programming languages.

Excel counts from 1900-01-01 unlike UNIX that counts from 1970-01-01.
The number returned is a float value of the number of days from 1900-01-01, and the fraction of the float is the time of the day.

As an example `25861.5` is 1970-10-20 12:00 ("Y-m-d h.i").

To convert to UNIX you should take the returned value - 25569 (1970-01-01 in Excel) and multiply with 86400 (one day in seconds).

See here: 
https://3v4l.org/AudMn

In Excel if you format 25861 and 25569 as dates:
[image]

The other float you got `43195.4092013889`

```
echo date("Y-m-d h:i", (43195.4092013889-25569)*86400); //2018-04-05 11:49 (mind the timezones)
```

https://3v4l.org/mMZQ4

Comment: This formula almost works but it seems to be one day off. That said using the functions PHPSpreadSheet provides is also a day off. My raw value is 43559 and using your formula it comes out as 2019-04-03 but the spreadsheet cell shows 04/04/2019 (this is in the US). Using the functions PHPSpreadSheet surprised it also shows the 2019-04-03 which is not correct. `echo date('Y-m-d h:i',\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToTimestamp(43559));`

Comment: @Dave as I wrote in the answer "mind the timezone". Unix is 0 timezone and US is on the negative scale. Since your Excel value doesn't know anything about timezones then it returns the value as is. But PHP is timezone aware and returns the time in your timezone based as the input value is in GMT. So add the number of hours you are after GMT to the line of code and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, that pushed me in the right direction.

Comment: For completeness here's what worked (note the use of the PHPSpreadsheet built-in function for date conversion .... the 14400 is the 4 hours behind GMT that the Eastern US is right now) `echo date('Y-m-d h:i',(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToTimestamp(43559) + 14400));`

Answer (score 4):

Another way to solve that feature is getting the active sheet from our object PHPSpreadSheet and change the style as follows:

```
$sheet = $PhpSpreadSheetObject->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->getStyle("A1:Z1")->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode("YYYY-MM-DD");
```